# Extract multiple grids from HDF with subset tool using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, hdf

This should be fairly simple thing but bugging me at the moment. I have ~5k HDF files in a folder with names:

```
MOD11A1.A2001001.h24v05.005.2006343042921
and so on.....
```

I have following which loop through all of them to extract a subset grid from each HDF file. For unknown reason, python script breaks down every time at around file number 3557. I am able to manually extract several grids around that number from HDF files. Maybe, I am hitting RAM limit. But even with all other applications closed, it exhibits same behavior.

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")
for inLST in rasters:
    f = inLST[9:16]
    outLST = "D:/temp/subset/" + str(f) + '_lst'
    arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(inLST, outLST, "0")
```

Is there any alternate to `arcpy.ListRasters`, which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extracting more than 1k files might possibly have saturated memory with file path name `"D:/temp/subset/" + str(f) + '_lst'`. However I was able to run it by reducing path to `"D:/" + str(f) + '_lst'`. Following is complete snippet that worked for me:

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")
for inLST in rasters:
    f = inLST[9:16]
    outLST = "D:/" + str(f) + '_lst'
    arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(inLST, outLST, "0")
```